# I have a table in webpage in that I have an interface as shown in image. by matching interface name i need to click on arrow

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]I have an webpage in that i have a table by matching to interfacecode i need to click on arrow.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/descendant::span[contains(text(),'STR_PGW.RETURN')]/parent::tr/td/descendant::button[@class='kbnDocTableOpen__button']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void payload(WebDriver driver, BaseTest basetest) throws Exception {

```
    List<WebElement> PayloadXml = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@ng-repeat='field in fields']"));
    System.out.println("payload");

    for (WebElement P : PayloadXml)
        System.out.println(P.getText());

    List<WebElement> PayloadXmlvalues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='kbnDocViewer__value']"));
    String payload = "<CreditReturnRequest>";
    for (WebElement V : PayloadXmlvalues)
        System.out.println(V.getText());

    for (int i = 0; i <= PayloadXmlvalues.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.println("Content text is : " + PayloadXml.get(i).getText());
        // match the content here in the if loop
        if (PayloadXml.get(i).getText().contains(payload)) {

            String xmlvalues = PayloadXmlvalues.get(i).getText();
            String xmlOutputFile = "data.xml";
```